# Outputs always X using assign statement for creating bcs

Tags: verilog

I created a BCS using assign statement, and it is compiled successfully. Then I wrote a testbench for it, and my problem is that my outputs in the waveform are X constantly.

This is my BCS :

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module BCS_assigned(input e0,g0,a0,b0,output e1,g1);
   assign #29 e1=(a0~^b0)&e0;
   assign #33 g1=(~a0&b0&e0)|g0;
endmodule
```

And this is my testbench for BCS :

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module assigned_BCS_testbench();
    wire e1, g1;
    reg a0;
    reg b0;
    reg e0;
    reg g0;
    BCS_assigned bcs(e0,g0,a0,b0,e1,g1);
    initial begin
        #0 a0=0;
        #0 a0=0;
        #0 e0=0;
        #0 g0=0;
        #5
        #0 a0=1;
        #0 b0=1;
        #0 e0=1;
        #0 g0=1;
        #5
        #0 a0=0;
        #0 b0=0;
        #0 e0=1;
        #0 g0=0;
        #5
        #5 $stop;
    end
endmodule
```

Why my outputs are X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the simulation for a longer time.  For example, change:

```
    #5 $stop;
```

to

```
    #100 $stop;
```

The problem is that your testbench stops the simulation at time 20ns, but that does not allow enough time for the `assign` delays (29 and 33) to propagate.  With this change, I see `e1` go from X to 1 at time 39ns.